# Building a chat application, NodeJS and Express - what should I use for media streaming?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, chat, live-streaming

I've previously built chat servers using NodeJS (i.e. central chat server with clients, no p2p), with Electron, or just good old Express.  I'd like to re-use as much of my old code as possible.  Thus, the only missing piece of the puzzle for me is what to use to enable both public and private video/audio streaming.  File sending isn't necessary.

Is there anything out there I can 'easily' drop in to this model?  I'm aware of Kurento and a few similar offerings but these feel like overkill for how I'm hoping to work.

**update**: Given a few suggestions about WebRTC, which I'm open to, but plans for this app include automated moderation/content filtering of any video broadcasts and text.  So I assume such a solution would need to either treat the server as a 'hardcoded' peer somehow so that it's fairly safe to assume it will see a copy of anything sent over the public chat network.  Of course, for private communications this need not be the case.  On the flip side, worst case, operating in a spoke topology is fine too.

Comment: what about web RTC?

Comment: honestly, I don't understand it well enough to be able to cut out the stuff I don't want.  I just found node-media-server which looks promising.  Although I'd have to figure out how to make it 'secure'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a WebRTC samples
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

WebRTC is kind of standard now for audio/video calls. It's all work p2p with no server interaction. 
The only one thing you need to build is a signaling protocol to connect 2 users. For this you can use/extend your nodejs app chat.

Comment: Thanks for this. One major reason I'm a little reluctant about WebRTC is I want the server to be involved, either as a simulated Peer or in a spoke arrangement.  The main reason is somewhat proprietary at this stage but call it automated content moderation.  So far I haven't seen an example of that kind of use, which would be helpful for me.

Comment: You mean you just want to relay all your traffic via server with no server processing? or to behave a server  like a client?

Comment: Not necessarily in this case.  I will update my question with more detail.